# What to do when main is intended, yet being detected not intended in python?

Tags: python

in a program in python, I defined the main function in the beginning of program and executed it at the very last. And when I compiled the code, a weird syntax error is being shown(check attachment)...

This is the code:

```
from cs50 import get_string

def main():
    s = get_string("Text: ")
    
    words = countw(s)
    letters = countl(s)
    sentences = counts(s)

    l = (letters/words) * 100
    s = (sentences/words) * 100
    
    index = (0.0588 * 1) - (0.296 * s) - 15.8
    i = round(index)

    print(words)
    print(letters)

    if i < i:
        print("Before Grade 1")
    elif i > 16:
        print("Grade 16+")
    else:
        print("Grade " + str(i))

def countw(string):
    s = len(string.split())
    return s

def countl(string):
    s = len(string)
    return s

def counts(string):
    #todo

main()
```

This is the error:

```
ss@comp:/mnt/c/Users/comp/desktop$ python3 readability.py

  File "readability.py", line 37

    main()

    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: What is the implementation of `def counts(string):`? Did you mean `return 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your counts() function is empty.

The interpreter thinks your call to the main() is meant to be part of that function and therefore sends an error.

Try to comment out your `def counts(string):` line:

```py
#def counts(string):
    #todo
```

As @quamrana pointed out, that would cause an error when you will call the counts function. You should therefore hard code a value for your sentences variable until you have finished coding counts().

---

You could also just write a return statement in your function, returning a value you would except it to return when you are done coding it, like so:

```py
def counts(string):
    #todo
    return 10
```

(Assuming 10 is a reasonable value for your sentences variable)

Comment: Or write `pass` before or after the comment.

Comment: Commenting out `def counts()` will just produce a different error.

Comment: because `main()` calls `counts()`. So without it there will be an error.

Comment: and actually an implementation of `pass` would make `counts()` return `None`, which would also produce another error later.